# Como dar Match em palavra com várias alternativas?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando dar **match** nos `type` de `input` que existem, porém a palavra `"datetime-local"` está me trazendo problemas, pois se for `"datetime"` ele também encontra um *match*.

Para a minha expressão ficar correta eu preciso que ela encontre a partir de uma `string` de `char` inserida somente as palavras correspondentes a mesma, ou seja, para ser `true` no caso do `"datetime"` a palavra inserida precisaria ser `"datetime-local"` e não somente `"datetime"`.

**Como posso corrigir esta expressão?**

```js
 const regExpTypes = new RegExp(
      "button$|color$|date$|datetime(-local)$|email$|file$|hidden$|image$|month$|password$|radio$|range$|reset$|search$|submit$|tel$|text$|time$|url$|week$"
);
    
console.log(regExpTypes.test("datetime"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`), a regex vai tentando as alternativas da esquerda para a direita, até encontrar uma que sirva.

No caso, se a entrada é a string `datetime`, a regex não encontra o *match* nas 16 primeiras alternativas (inclusive na quarta - `datetime(-local)$` - que procura por algo que termine com `datetime-local`, e veja que os parênteses não fazem diferença aqui).

Na alternativa 17 (`time$`) ela encontra um *match*, já que este trecho significa "termina com `time`", e `datetime` corresponde a isso. Por isso sua regex retorna `true` para a string `datetime`.

[A sua solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396309/112052) funcionou porque você acrescentou `^`, então a alternativa "começa com `datetime-local`" passa a dar *match* - e `datetime` não dá mais *match* porque você mudou `time$` (termina com `time`) para `^time` (começa com `time`).

Mas enfim, se você quer verificar se uma string corresponde exatamente a algum dos nomes que estão na regex, pode mudá-la para:

```js
 const regExpTypes = new RegExp(
   "^(button|color|date|datetime-local|email|file|hidden|image|month|password|radio|range|reset|search|submit|tel|text|time|url|week)$"
 );
    
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("datetime")); // false
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("datetime-local")); // true
```

Esta regex tem os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Em seguida, entre eles há uma alternância com todas as alternativas que você quer capturar.

---

Repare que todas as alternativas estão entre parênteses, pois isso faz diferença.
Se eu fizer, por exemplo, `^button|color$`, isso significa "começa com `button`, ou termina com `color`" - e caso comece com `button`, pode inclusive ter mais coisas depois; caso termine com `color`, pode ter mais coisas antes - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/TNoN2b/1/):

```js
 const regExpTypes = /^button|color$/;

 console.log(regExpTypes.test("button")); // true
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("button123")); // true
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("color")); // true
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("123color")); // true
```

Já se eu colocar `^(button|color)$`, isso significa "início da string", seguido de `button` ou `color`, seguido do final da string. Ou seja, a string só pode ter o que está nas alternativas, nenhum caractere a mais, nem a menos ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/TNoN2b/2/)).

```js
 const regExpTypes = /^(button|color)$/;

 console.log(regExpTypes.test("button")); // true
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("button123")); // false
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("color")); // true
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("123color")); // false
```

Então se você quer que a string seja exatamente alguma das alternativas, use `^(alternativas)$`.

---

Dá para simplificar um pouco mais:

```js
 const regExpTypes = new RegExp(
   "^(button|color|date(time-local)?|email|file|hidden|image|month|password|ra(dio|nge)|reset|search|submit|te(l|xt)|time|url|week)$"
 );
    
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("datetime")); // false
 console.log(regExpTypes.test("datetime-local")); // true
```

Fiz algumas modificações:

- `date(time-local)?`: o trecho `time-local` está entre parênteses, e o `?` logo depois torna-o [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). Sendo assim, este trecho pega `date` ou `datetime-local` (mas não `datetime`)
- `ra(dio|nge)`: pega as strings `radio` ou `range`
- `te(l|xt)`: pega as strings `tel` ou `text`

---

#### Sem regex

Mas para este caso talvez seja mais simples ter um array com as alternativas válidas, e então verificar se a string está neste array, usando o método [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
 const validos = ['button', 'color', 'date', 'datetime-local', 'email',
                 'file', 'hidden', 'image', 'month', 'password', 'radio',
                 'range', 'reset', 'search', 'submit', 'tel', 'text', 'time', 'url', 'week'];
    
 console.log(validos.includes("datetime")); // false
 console.log(validos.includes("datetime-local")); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

[A resposta do Marconi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396298/112052) não me convém, porém utilizei o [link](https://regex101.com/r/2rhlVv/1) citado pelo mesmo para fins de testes, e cheguei a seguinte conclusão que funciona do seguinte modo:

```
button|color$|date$|^datetime-local|email$|file$|hidden$|image$|month$|password$|radio$|range$|reset$|search$|submit$|tel$|text$|^time|url$|week$
```

Onde as palavras `datetime-local` e `time`, devem utilizar o operador `^` e as demais o operador `$`.

**$**

> Corresponde ao final do texto. Se a flag multilinhas é setada para true, também se aplica imediatamente antes de um caractere de quebra de linha. Por exemplo, `/r$/` não corresponde ao 'r' em "corre", mas acha correspondência em "correr".

**^**

> Corresponde ao início do texto. Se a flag multilinhas é setada para  true, também se aplica imediatamente após um caractere de quebra de linha. Por exemplo, `/^A/` não corresponde ao 'A' em "Um Alvo", mas corresponde ao 'A' em "Alvo Encontrado".